# Error due to a field

Tags: apex, visualforce, dynamic-vf-component

Getting an error

> Error: Variable does not exist: itemDisplay

**Controller**

```
public class StoreFrontController {
    list<productDisplay> prd;
    public list<product__c> getProducts()
    {
        if(prd == null)
        {
            prd = new list<productDisplay>();
            for(Product__c pLoop : [select name, id, price__c, condition__c, quantity__c, stock__c from product__c])
                {
                    prd.add(productDisplay(itemDisplay));    
                }
        }
        return prd;
    }
    public class productDisplay
    {
        private Product__c p;
        productDisplay(Product__c itemDisplay)
        {
            this.p = itemDisplay;
        }
        public String name
        {
            get{return p.name;}
        }
        public Decimal pPrice
        {
            get{return p.price__c;}
        }
        public String pCondition
        {
            get{return p.condition__c;}
        }
        public Decimal pStock
        {
            get{return(p.Stock__c);}
        }
        public Decimal pQuantity
        {
            get{return(p.Quantity__c);}
            set;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `itemDisplay` variable is not defined inside of `for` loop.

Comment: @MahmoodButt -- you should post your comment as answer so we can get this question cleared

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the change

```
public list<product__c> getProducts()
{
    if(prd == null)
    {
       prd = new list<productDisplay>();
       for(Product__c pLoop : [select name, id, price__c, condition__c, quantity__c, stock__c 
       from product__c])
       {
          prd.add(productDisplay(itemDisplay));    
       }
    }
    return prd;
}
```